# Redefinition of enumerator in two seperate frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I have two frameworks included in one of my files

```
#import "SCLAlertView.h"
#import "ActionSheetStringPicker.h"
```

These frameworks are unfortunately fighting against each other and are trying to define the same constant.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, SCLActionType)
{
    None,
    Selector,
    Block
};

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ActionType)
{
    Value,
    Selector,
    Block
};
```

Is there an easy solution to a redefinition of enumerator? I could change the code, but I would prefer not to, since any update of the frameworks will revert my changes and require me to redo it once again.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed one of the frameworks.